# Баг с Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap, dropzone

Я хочу создать "дропзону" внутри модального окна бутстрапа, для загрузки фото/видео но уже пару дней не могу разобраться с библиотекой Dropzone.js, постоянно возникают какие либо ошибки, использовал CDN версию библиотеки , но сейчас скачал через composer, ничего не помогает, подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так, ниже прилагаю код, скрины из консоли, а также скрин модального окна (когда переношу файл или нажимаю на дропзону ничего не происходит)

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <div class="d-flex mb-3">
                    <div class="avatar avatar-xs me-2">
                        <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="{{auth()->user()->img}}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <form id="addPost_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="w-100" novalidate>
                        <div class="">
                        <textarea name="content" id="addPost_input" class="form-control pe-4 fs-3 lh-1 border-0" rows="4" placeholder="Что у вас нового?" autofocus></textarea>
                         {{--<input id="img_post" name="img_post" type="file">
                        <input id="video_post" name="video_post" type="file">--}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="addPost_dropzone" id="addPost_dropzone">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="dz-message">
                                    <i class="bi bi-images display-3"></i>
                                    <p>Выберите файл или перетащите его сюда</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="addPost_button" onclick="addPost()" aria-label="Close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success-soft" value="Опубликовать">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <script>
                    var addPost_dropzone = new Dropzone("div#addPost_dropzone", {
                        createImageThumbnails: false,
                        addRemoveLinks: true,
                        url: "(/addPost)"
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
```

[image: ошибки в консоли]

[image: скрин странички]